Unable to query against secondary replica mongodb
I am trying to query against secondary replica by opening mongoshell query window for secondary node using Studio3t. However, I am unable to run query against secondary node
Error:
MongoServerError: not primary and secondaryOk=false - consider using db.getMongo().setReadPref() or readPreference in the connection string
my Studio3t connection 'read preference' set to Primary so that may be the reason i am not able to run query against secondary.
Can I use following command to connect to secondary node and will it be limited to existing session only?
db.collection.find({ }).readPref( "secondary")
or
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')

nevermind. I found an answer.run the following command before running runcommand.
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')
